# Display results of second array in nested array php dump

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following code:

```php
public function canceledReasons()
{
   $searchs = Zendesk::search()->find('type:ticket tags:cancel');
   $searchs = json_decode(json_encode($searchs),true);
   foreach ($searchs as $search) {
        dump($search);
   }
}
```

It returns an array that has some nested arrays in them I'm trying to display the second array in "tags" if it exists. There might be more than one array in there so it might be good to display them all.
`Results`

```
array:100 [▼
  0 => array:36 [▼
    "url" => "https://example/api/v2/tickets/example.json"
    "id" => example
    "external_id" => null
    "via" => array:2 [ …2]
    "created_at" => "2019-08-28T02:05:22Z"
    "updated_at" => "2019-08-29T23:00:54Z"
    "type" => null
    "subject" => "example"
    "raw_subject" => "example"
    "description" => """
      From: example\n
      Phone: \n
      Location: example\n
      URL: https://example.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/categories/#####-Account-Billing\n
      Department: \n
      \n
      Hi,\n
      please cancel  ▶
      \n
      Best,\n
      Vinay\n
      \n
      ----\n
      Zopim\n
      https://www.example.com
      """
    "priority" => null
    "status" => "open"
    "recipient" => "example"
    "requester_id" => example
    "submitter_id" => example
    "assignee_id" => example
    "organization_id" => null
    "group_id" => example
    "collaborator_ids" => []
    "follower_ids" => []
    "email_cc_ids" => []
    "forum_topic_id" => null
    "problem_id" => null
    "has_incidents" => false
    "is_public" => true
    "due_at" => null
    "tags" => array:2 [ …2]
    "custom_fields" => array:2 [ …2]
    "satisfaction_rating" => null
    "sharing_agreement_ids" => []
    "fields" => array:2 [ …2]
    "followup_ids" => []
    "brand_id" => example
    "allow_channelback" => false
    "allow_attachments" => true
    "result_type" => "ticket"
  ]
  1 => array:36 [▶]
  2 => array:36 [▶]
  3 => array:36 [▶]
  4 => array:36 [▶]
```

When I try

```
dump($search['tags']);
```

It returns Undefined index: tags

Just trying to get the results of the 'tags' arrays.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

````
public function canceledReasons()
{

  $searchs = Zendesk::search()->find('type:ticket tags:cancel');
  $searchs = json_decode(json_encode($searchs),true);

  foreach ($searchs as $search) {
    dump($search[0]['tags']);
     //or to get all tags array value
    foreach ($search[0]['tags'] as $tag) {
       dump($tag);
    }
  }
}
    ```
````

Comment: for dump($search[0]['tags']); I get Illegal string offset 'tags'   for the second one I get Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
I do see the 1st result of the tags array but only once instance.

Comment: Also, this looks at only the 0 arrays I need to iterate through all of them and pull out tags.